# Can a lattice be bounded and NOT Complete?

Tags: lattice-orders

Can a lattice be bounded and not complete and if yes can you please show an example?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Bounded_lattice and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of a bounded lattice that is NOT complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800429/example-of-a-bounded-lattice-that-is-not-complete)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathbb{Q} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$, which is a total order and hence a bounded lattice. However, there is no supremum of $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 < 2\}$.